# Create a single raster file from a raster file with multiple layers and average the pixel values

Tags: average, r-raster, r-stars

I have to convert a raster file of class "stars" that contains 30 layers (30 values at each pixel) (466 x 435 x 30), to a new raster file of the same type (stars) with a single layer (466 x 435 x 1). For each pixel, its value should equal the average value of the 30 layers at the corresponding pixel. Below I am showing a screenshot of the raster file, called sim, taken from R studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SVh7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `stars` object is named `r`, the following expressions calculates the average per pixel (excluding `NA`). `st_apply` is used to apply the `mean` function over dimensions `1:2`, namely the pixels.

```r
st_apply(r, 1:2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Here is another example and more information:

https://geobgu.xyz/r/raster-processing.html#pixel-means